# Python Panda3D - Render using Coordinates

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, rendering, panda3d

I have encountered an error, i'm trying to render a character using coordinates of the character and then using the code reparentTo(render), however i get the following error: "TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None".

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\On
  line.py", line 1857, in <module>
  run()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 2921, in run
  self.taskMgr.run()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\task\Task.py", line 502, in run
  self.step()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\task\Task.py", line 460, in step
  self.mgr.poll()
  File "C:\On
  line.py", line 1591, in updaterender
  s.send(x)
  TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Part of the Client code:

```
import direct.directbase.DirectStart
import pickle
from direct.gui.OnscreenText import OnscreenText
from direct.gui.DirectGui import *
from panda3d.core import *
from pandac.PandaModules import CardMaker
from pandac.PandaModules import NodePath
import socket
import sys
import select
print("Connecting...")
name = "fatie"
print 'Please enter the name you wish to use for your pirate?'
name = raw_input()
host = 'localhost'
port = 8303
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

     # connect to remote host
try :
     s.connect((host, port))
except :
    print 'Unable to connect'
    sys.exit()
#When the connection is established the game loads.
#So if the code "Connected" comes up, the connection has been established.
print("Connected")
print("Loading Game")

#Game Loads Info connection to files then half way down the code

def updatecoords(task):
    s.send(name)
    print 'Name sent...'

def updatepos(task):

    y = format(Cat.getPos())
    s.send(y)

def updaterender(task):

    x = Cat.reparentTo(render)
    s.send(x)
    return Task.cont
    print 'Position sent'

 def readServer(task):
    try:
        data = s.recv(4096)
        print data
        return Task.cont
    except:
        print 'no data received'

#Then further down

 base.taskMgr.add(handleMovement, 'controlManager')
 base.taskMgr.add(updatecoords, 'network coords')
 base.taskMgr.add(updaterender, 'network coords')
 base.taskMgr.add(updatepos, 'network coords')
 base.taskMgr.add(readServer, 'read in')
```

Server Code:

```
import socket
import time
import pickle
import select
def broadcast(sock, message):

    for socket in CONNECTION:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection may be, chat client pressed ctrl+c for example
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION.remove(socket)




HOST = ""
PORT = 8303
CONNECTION = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 
maxclients = 5

print "Online Server started on port " + str(PORT)  
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('',PORT))
server_socket.listen(maxclients)
CONNECTION.append(server_socket)




 while 1:

         read_socks,wri_socks,err_socks = select.select(CONNECTION,[],[])

         for sock in read_socks:
            #New connection
            if sock == server_socket:

                 socknew, addr = server_socket.accept()

                 CONNECTION.append(socknew)

                 print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

                 broadcast(socknew, "[%s:%s] entered game\n" % addr)


             else:

                 try:

                    data = socknew.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        print data

                     #  broadcast_data(sock,data) 
                     #  print 'data was broadcast to'
                     #  print CONNECTION_LIST.len()
                except:
                     broadcast(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                     sock.close()
                     CONNECTION.remove(sock)
                     continue

 server_socket.close()
```

Comment: `reparentTo` is a function that doesn't return anything, so what are you trying to accomplish by trying to send None over a socket (which isn't possible, hence the error)?  What kind of value did you expect reparentTo to return?

Comment: I should add that your tasks aren't guaranteed to run in a particular order unless you specify a different sort value to each taskMgr.add call.  I'm not sure how it makes sense in general to separate out the different chunks of data via tasks, but certainly, you'd want the order to be predictable. :-)